# Using ∞ instead of "infinity" in toString()

Tags: java, numbers, special-characters, tostring, infinity

How can I make Java use the ∞ symbol instead of the string "infinity" when printing/toString'ing floating-point values (float, double, Float, Double)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change the default `toString` method, which isn't for user display but for debug/logging.

But you may configure your own [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) :

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
symbols.setInfinity("∞");
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#####", symbols);
```

You use it like this :

```
String str = decimalFormat.format(myDouble);
```

Note that the formater will automatically add a minus sign in case of negative infinity.

Comment: What do you mean the *"default DecimalFormat"* ? DecimalFormat is a class you instantiate for your needs. You build an instance and you use it where you want.

Comment: I meant, change the default behavior of `Double.toString()`, i.e. change the default behavior of `FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString()`. I've mistakenly assumed that involved a DecimalFormat object.